# iOS: Play Spotify Audio in silent mode

Tags: audio, swift3, ios10, spotify

i'm developping app using spotify-iOS-SDK, i have succesfully connect my app to Spotify and my audio is playing, but the problem is: When i activated silent mode, there is no sound come from my app even though spotify music is still playing. I have checked other apps using Spotify-iOS-SDK (Demo Project, MusixMatch) and all of them can release the sound

Here's my code:

```
        self.spotifyPlayer = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.spotifyPlayer!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.spotifyPlayer!.delegate = self

        try! spotifyPlayer?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)            
        self.spotifyPlayer!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
```

then, this function will be called:

```
func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {
    let uri = "spotify:track:" + trackId
    self.spotifyPlayer?.playSpotifyURI(uri, startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (error) in
           if (error != nil) {
                print("error: \(error) ")
           }
    })
}
```

Comment: does the `didStartPlayingTrack` delegate get hit? You might want to look at `audioStreamingDidBecomeInactivePlaybackDevice` and `didReceiveError` delegate methods.

Comment: `didStartPlayingTrack` is running smoothly, i also called some function right after the track is playing, `audioStreamingDidBecomeInactivePlaybackDevice` will be called after my PlaySongViewController is closed, not because i silent my phone, and for `didReceiveError` doesn't get called anywhere

Answer (score 3):

i have figured it out what i'm missing

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didChangePlaybackStatus isPlaying: Bool) {
    print("isPlaying: \(isPlaying)")
    if (isPlaying) {
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } else {
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    }

}
```